# SQL: different amount of data

Tags: sql

I have a two-step task at hand: first, a certain join should be performed:

```
  Select *
  FROM [my_table2]b
  left join [my_table3]c
  on (b.CUSTOMER_PK=c.CUSTOMER_PK)
  where c.CUSTOMER_PK is null
```

That worked perfectly and gave me certain 2985 rows needed for the next step (to verify all the received  data do appear in another table:

```
SELECT  *
FROM [my_table1]a 
where a.customer_id in (Select b.customer_id 
FROM [my_table2]b
left join [my_table3]c
on (b.CUSTOMER_PK=c.CUSTOMER_PK)
where c.CUSTOMER_PK is null)
```

For some reason, it gave me a bit more lines - 2996 (same result when DISTINCT was used with all the column names). However, when I try to find out - by means of EXCEPT (no MINUS supported) what the extra 11 rows are (I only need to receive one column identical in all the tables in terms of its data type - decimal (9, 0)), I get no results. Any idea what goes wrong?
Here's the third query:

```
Select customer_id
FROM [my_table1]a 
where a.customer_id in (Select b.customer_id 
FROM [my_table2]b
left join [my_table3]c
on (b.CUSTOMER_PK=c.CUSTOMER_PK)
where c.CUSTOMER_PK is null)
EXCEPT
Select customer_id
FROM [my_table2]b
left join [my_table3]c
on (b.CUSTOMER_PK=c.CUSTOMER_PK)
where c.CUSTOMER_PK is null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the `customer_id`s from the first select have more than one record with a corresponding `customer_id` in `[my_table1]`.

To find out which IDs are duplicates, you could use something like this

```
SELECT a.customer_id, count(*)
FROM [my_table1]a 
left join [my_table2]b on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id)
left join [my_table3]c on (b.CUSTOMER_PK = c.CUSTOMER_PK)
where c.CUSTOMER_PK is null
group by a.customer_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that a single customer has multiple rows in the first table `my_table1`.  You can look for such customers by doing:

```
select a.customer_id, count(*) as cnt
from my_table1 a
group by a.customer_id
having count(*) > 1
order by cnt desc;
```

Of course, this does it for all values, not just the matching ones.  This might give you an idea of where the problem is.  Otherwise, use the same approach but with the `in` clause.

The problem is *not* duplicates in the `b` and `c` tables.  The `in` clause doesn't produce duplicates on output.